# Why do I get a declined flags warning when there's only one that's recent?

Tags: support, flags

When attempting to flag a post, got the following warning in the flag window

> [image]

Great warning, but there is one problem. I don't really have any recently declined flags besides one on April 14th which hasn't caused any trouble before. And my flag history seems to be quite decent with almost 2600 helpful flags and rarely any declined ones.

So what gives? What causes this warning? Is the system now pre-emptively trying to tell me my flagging will suck?

Comment: Do you have any old close vote flags? If those questions finally got handled in review, and people didn't vote to close them, that might have led to a few of those being declined recently even though they were cast a while ago.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of @BradLarson. From what I know my flags were all handled besides a couple of recent ones

Comment: [Shog's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405) says, *Flaggers with a recent (past 7 days) flagging history consisting of at least 10 flags where >= 10% of flags were declined will see the following when they flag...* So that's probably why.

Comment: Myeah, I just don't get to that >= 10% figure @hichris123. I keep a pretty good eye on whether or not my flags have been handled. But I guess I must have missed something.

Comment: *sigh* The pains of having a ton of flags. Now go through your entire flag history to check if anything has been handled recently @Bart!

Comment: */me contemplates a "sort by handle date" request*

Comment: @Bart Yes, please!

Comment: @Bart - Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226361/can-we-make-new-flag-responses-more-visible