# Flag banned after getting a helpful flag

Tags: bug, flags, flag-ban

I was flagging questions asking [recommending tools](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22Is+there+a+tool%22+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano) [or](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3a%22Is%20there%20a%20good%20tool%22%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano) [library](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22Is+there+a+library%22+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano) when I received this after getting a helpful flag on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23431363/2284570):

[image: I CAN'T flag anything DURING A WEEK!]

I had this message directly, without having the usual warning :

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!

Moreover, the past 7 handled flags were deemed helpful. I have 19 declined flags since several days and I am **sure about this time and amount** *(no mistakes)*.
The first handled flag of the past 10 days and also 20 days is a declined flag. I could continue to review after I got two helpful flag after it.

A workaround can be that some persons review the flags on the picture above *(or add other flags when it is relevant, so they'll appear in the close queue)*:

[image: My flagging summary]

**Update** : The post linked as duplicate don't talk of a bug. It tell he has been flag-banned after *getting a declined flag* which can look normal. I already knew and used [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/242800) link my comments, and I'm not asking how this does work *(please read this question : I'm talking about the conditions of such bans)*.
What happened is that I have been banned **after getting an *helpful* flag**, and it didn't represent 25% of declined flags in the past 7 days.

Comment: Given the 111 still waiting for review, this might well be the cause of several older flags being handled (and declined) recently.

Comment: Certainly not a bug, but simply the fact that the flag banning takes into account your most recently handled flags, regardless of the age of the flag, so there's no way to tell which flags triggered the ban.

Comment: Related feature request from MSE: [Can we make new flag responses more visible?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226361/can-we-make-new-flag-responses-more-visible)

Comment: @Bart this because I only flag very old-post *(I won't happen if you flag active posts)*. The system make they can't get reviewed. I tried to discuss of this specific problem for old flags and ask for a solution : [but it failed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228615/242800).

Comment: 19% of total _reviewed_ flags were declined, 14% disputed, 4 post flagged as "offensive" & "spam" were declined. Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: @psubsee2003 : Didn't you read my question? I already said that the last 7 handled flags were deemed helpful, and that last declined flag was handled several days ago.

Comment: @user2284570 how do you know your last 7 were deemed helpful? (that was kind of my point)

Comment: @Omar : "*4 post flagged as "offensive" & "spam" were declined.*" I already got flag-ban period for this : it was a mounth ago. Moreover, [flag-bans occurs at 25% of declined flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/242800) not 14%.

Comment: @psubsee2003 : Again the process of reviewing old posts [is very long](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228615/242800). So, they are reviewed one by one *(I'm a guy who constantly watch his flag summary)*. There also the date which tell when the flag was handled I checked them carefully before writing this question. When something like this happen, I try to look for my mistakes; but I'm sure the mistake come from the system in my case. I couldn't flag anything just after this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23431363/2284570) was handled *(look at the dates gaps between each flag)*.

Comment: @user2284570 fair enough, but for every user who actually has an accurate picture of what actually happened, there are a 100 that insist they know their own history but leave out key facts, so you have to accept that users on Meta will not necessarily trust when you insist you are correct.... but still not a bug, just how the math is working out.

Comment: Then again @psubsee2003 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251335/why-do-i-get-a-declined-flags-warning-when-theres-only-one-thats-recent ... And I didn't have old flags waiting to be handled.

Comment: @Bart: hmm, weird. Is it flags *cast* in the past 7 days or flags *handled*? Seems there's something weird with what counts for what.

Comment: @psubsee2003 : I am aware I have no informations to get trusted *(only someone who have access to the database can tell I'm not wrong)*. This is a bug because the system aim at stop peoples who flag incorrectly : not those who try to carefully flag things.

Comment: @OneKitten : Not the "past 7 days" but the "past 7 handled flags".

Comment: @OneKitten : Ok, but in that case I should have been banned 3 days ago : not know!

Comment: By the way, a workaround to leave the ban is that some peoples who read this review the flags in my history with those on the screenshot.

Comment: @user2284570: also, regular users can't ban you as you think I did (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431363/best-tool-for-javascript-ci?noredirect=1#comment35955517_23431363)

Comment: Maybe it is me but I have raised 1568 flags and only 8 declined flags...are you sure you flag correctly?

Comment: @PatrickHofman In reality we can (indirectly).  Flags to close questions get sent into the close-vote queue, and those flags are marked as helpful or declined based on the responses of the users who encounter that question in the close-vote queue.  Enough users click "Leave Open" and the flag is declined.  Enough vote to close, and it is marked as helpful.  And if the user picks up enough declined flags, they will be banned from flagging.

Comment: @psubaee2003: yeah. You are right. But that is a community decision, not a single user (mod) that does it. Don't know why OP thinks I handle bans.

Comment: @psubsee2003 : No they don't get in the close-vote queue, because the queue is currently fuzzied. Only questions with at least 2 close votes appear in the review queue. Knew posts get in the close-vote queue, when at least 2 users raised flags outside of it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman : Yes I know that is don't happen. I never said it can be done manually. It was the result of an automatic system.

Comment: @user2284570: you said: "You rated my flag as helpful. Because you didn't voted to close the question, I'm flag-banned now." I did not rate your flag as helpful. And before you flagged I already did the VtC.

Comment: @PatrickHofman :Which probably could be a "*reason/result*" for the system.

Comment: @user2284570: I would stop blame the system and check you accepted/declined ratio.

Comment: @PatrickHofman : It can't be done anymore : most flags on my screenshot have been rated helpful. I'm flagging again now.

Answer (score 25):

Referencing [Shog's answer explaining the new flag ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405), you are judged only on flags handled within the last 7 days, and you are banned when 25% of those flags are declined.

In general, the flag ban deals with 3 different variables, any of which will change the status of the ban.

1. Total number of **handled** flags.  Handled is the operative word as the ban is based on when flags were handled and not when the flags were actually raised.
2. Total number of flags marked as declined.
3. Time - specifically when flags were handled as helpful and declined flags can age away, which will impact both (1) and (2) above.

So time is as much of an enemy here as declined flags.

For example, your flag history has 5 *declined* flags and 16 *helpful* flags in the last 7 days.  But if 4 of those "helpful" flags were 7 days ago, they will no longer be tracked.  If you only get 2 more flags handled to "replace" the 4 that no longer count, you'll be below the 25% threshold and will be subject to the ban.

So to summarize:

- 24% declined flags today on 21 total flags (16 helpful, 5 declined)
- By tomorrow, 4 helpful flags no longer count because they are >7 days ago, and you get only 2 new helpful flags.
- So you end up with 26% declined flags on 18 total flags (14 helpful, 5 declined) simply because you lost more helpful flags than you picked up

And this can change again as more flags are handled, or as more helpful and declined flags age away.

---

Now in your specific case, with the info you have provided, it is not immediately clear why you were banned.  Unfortunately, not even you can see when flags where handled in your flag summary, you can only see when you raised the flag and when the post you flagged was published, so it is impossible to determine exactly what flags are contributing to your flag ban.

You might be interested in [Can we make new flag responses more visible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226361/can-we-make-new-flag-responses-more-visible) and [Overview on my recent flagging activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226486/overview-on-my-recent-flagging-activity?lq=1), as both would help provide more insight into exactly what flags are being considered in the ban calculation.

Until such a feature is implemented, you have to manually keep track of when flags were handled.  Based on your comments and your edit to the question, it sounds like you are doing so:

> The first handled flag of the past 10 days and also 20 days is a declined flag. I could continue to review after I got two helpful flag after it.

However, so if your record keeping is accurate, it is not entirely clear why you have been banned, but as mentioned in the first half of this answer, it is entirely possible to have multiple helpful flags and still get banned based on aging of other flags.

Comment: Again, the first handled flag of the past 10 days and also 20 days is a declined flag. I could continue to review after I got two helpful flag after it.

Comment: Is there a place were I may upload the ten screenshots of my flagging history?

Comment: @user2284570 you don't need 10 screenshots of your flagging history, no one is going to spend the time reviewing it.  You've edited your last comment into your question now (with specific more details), so that helps address the problem.