# Misleading warning text: "some of your recent flags have been declined"

Tags: support, feature-request, flags, declined-flags

Why am I getting the [image: "Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!"] warning?

Looking at [my flag history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/119775?page=1), I can't see that I have triggered any of [the thresholds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405). I only have one declined flag this year, none in the past week.

---

### Answer and request

From rene and BoltClock's comments, it appears that the warning text is misleading. The recent thing is not the flags themselves, but rather the flag reviews resulting in declensions.

For example, a bunch of flags I raised years ago getting reviewed and declined today would trigger warnings and bans.

So this (**emphasis** mine):

> some of your **recent flags** have been declined

should in fact be

> some of your flags have been **declined recently**

Though to be honest, had I been reading this for the first time, I wouldn't have gotten the subtle difference and would still have been looking for recent flags being declined.

So I suggest the warning text be made clearer and a bit more explicit; perhaps something like this:

> Attention: some of your flags were recently evaluated and declined. Please review them before flagging this post!

Comment: Recent is not as in your recently rasised flags but your pending flags that were handeld recently by a mod/community. Could be that a bunch of flags you raised 3 years ago now all got declined...

Comment: This is a [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226486/overview-on-my-recent-flagging-activity) on MSE to make it easier to reach that info.

Comment: @rene A largely uncommented feature-request, unfortunately.

Comment: @J.Steen sure, there might be similar/better ones out there. It is a confusing user experience....

Comment: Yeah it sounds like it should say "some of your flags have been declined recently" instead.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, that would be semantically more correct. Though not very much clearer. I would definitely have missed that subtlety.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a declined flags warning when there's only one that's recent?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251335/why-do-i-get-a-declined-flags-warning-when-theres-only-one-thats-recent)

Comment: This question is tagged feature-request, the other is not. So I think the right thing to is not close as duplicate, [but I am not sure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279764/contents-of-question-x-is-dupe-of-old-question-y-but-x-only-has-tag-feature-r)

Comment: Is there bounty feature on meta?